# How to set floating point precision inside a variable

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

I am currently working a program where I need to calculate a rounded value to only 2 digits after a floating point.
Say, I have declared

```
float a;
```

If `a = 3.555` then it would store `a = 3.56`, rounding up.

For `a = 3.423`, the value of a would be `a = 3.423`, no change.

I can do this to print output, but what I need to do when storing it into a variable and use that variable for some other calculation?

Comment: Why would 3.423 be stored with 3 digits after the decimal point but 3.555 be stored with just 2 digits after the decimal point?

Comment: are you sure that for a = 3.423, the value of a would be a = 3.423?? not a=3.42??

Answer (score 5):

If you need two digits after the decimal point, don't use floating point. Use a fixed point number instead. For example, just use an integer that's 100 times larger than the decimal number you want to represent. Trying to fit a base 2 floating point number into rounding rules like this just isn't going to produce satisfactory results for you.

Comment: Right, and every time you want to use the number you'll have to fix its value. This is the sane solution.

Comment: In his question it seems that he want to do that after some calculation (thats why he need to round).

Comment: @fbafelipe You can still do all the math on the fixed point numbers.

Comment: Yes, but maybe it is just to display to the result to the user (after many operations that need more precision), and if he is not printing on console, formating with printf won't do, so he need what he is asking.

Answer (score 4):

```
    double d = 5000.23423;
    d = ceil(d*100)/100;
    cout << d << endl; // prints : 5000.24
    double e = 5000.23423;
    e = floor(e*100)/100; 
    cout << e << endl; // prints : 5000.23
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
a = roundf(a*100)/100;
```

Comment: This solution will have unexpected results if the unit of least precision is bigger than 1/100, which can happen if the absolute value of a is large.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
  double a, f, i;

  a = 3.436;
  f= modf(a, &i);
  a = i + roundf(f* 100.0) / 100.0;
  return 0;
}
```

Operates on doubles but avoids scaling the whole number.

**Update**: Added the missing division.