# Multiplying and dividing CGFloat and loss of precision

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CGFloat addition bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302384/cgfloat-addition-bug)

I have some code where I'm doing a lot of multiplying and dividing of `CGFloats` in order to figure out the correct dimensions for transformations. I notice sometimes when I'm suppose to get a value of 320, I'll get 320.00000092 instead. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to correct it? Is it suppose to be doing this? Here is some sample code where it's possible the problem might be happening:

```
- (void) setMinimumSize
{
    CGSize superViewSize = self.superview.bounds.size;
    CGSize size = self.frame.size;

    CGFloat xScale = superViewSize.width / size.width;
    CGFloat yScale = superViewSize.height / size.height;

    CGFloat minimumScale = MIN(xScale, yScale);
    self.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * minimumScale, size.height * minimumScale);
}

- (void) scaleToMinimumSize
{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, self.minimumSize.width / self.frame.size.width, self.minimumSize.height / self.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: As always when this type of questin appears: http://floating-point-gui.de

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't compare for equality, won't work for float (or double), rather compare 
the difference against some delta that suits your needs for accuracy

This is always an issue with decimal and floating points numbers.

Ask a middle school student (1/3.0)*3.0, all will say 1. Computer says 0.999999.

You cant expect, most of the time,  `0` to be `0.000000` it will never be near to that.

EDIT:

If float is in so much of use, you should read this one
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

And also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html),

Comment: That's not an explanation (as asked for in the question). Also, the stereotypical "equality won't work for float" is neither correct nor an issue in this case.

Comment: As OP "he exptects 320,but get 320.00000092 instead" that means he is trying to compare both the values. Also why 320 comes as 320.00000092 was another question. for that I menationed you cannot get 0.0000000 accuracy in floats.

Comment: I don't see a comparison in @CoDEFRo's code. But I do see him asking for an explanation.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe : I have added few more links and description, please let me know if it is fine

Comment: You just copied other people's answers (from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5334849/104790 and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10335601/104790) without mentioning the sources. Please understand that this is not welcome on SO.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe : sorry, from next time i wont copy anyone's answer and try to create my own new answers, explanations, logics etc ;(

Comment: Actually, 1/3.0 * 3.0 *is* exactly 1.0 when evaluated in IEEE-754 double-precision, and result that should be exactly zero are among the most likely to have noticeable errors.  Floating-point is subtle and generic answers that do not affect the specific question being asked are usually incorrect.

Comment: @StephenCanon: OK... I am deleting my answer.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe : OK... I am deleting my answer.

Comment: Your statement "Whenever you want a floating point value with some precision, you can take an integer and multiply it" also is wrong for many operations.